# Recording Piano Tutorials

Tags: piano, software, recording, digital-piano, homerecording

I'm thinking about starting a YouTube channel for piano tutorials, covers, etc. I have some equipment, but I'm just not sure how to put it all together. I would like to have a camera mounted over me showing the piano, real-time commentary about what I'm doing in the tutorial, and I would like to use MIDI to record my piano's sounds straight to my computer rather than just recording with a mic. I'm sure there are ways to do these things, but how can I put it all together.

Here are some of the materials I have:

GoPro Hero 3 (for recording video)

Roverbeats Headset w/ Microphone (for recording commentary; hearing myself play in real-time)

MIDI Input/Output to USB Converter (for recording audio from piano)

YAMAHA DGX-203 Digital Piano Keyboard (supports MIDI)

I know how to record the video. How do I make the videos sound include my commentary and my piano, all in  real-time so I can hear it in my headset as I'm recording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the right way to do it is to add the audio to the video afterwards, when you edit the video.

So normally, in the audio side, you should have one audio track with your commentary plus one MIDI track for the piano, which you will mix to your liking with your audio recording/editing software. Then you edit the video separately, to which you add the mixed audio.